# How exactly did Will and Barb get into the Upside-Down?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

Both Will and Barb from *Stranger Things* were hunted by the monster, who seems to have a tendency to take his victims into the Upside-Down before finally making use of them. It was quite logical in case of a deer: there was a portal open in the tree, the monster took the deer through it to the Upside-Down and ate a deer over there.

Say, with Barbara it is still explainable: the monster opens a portal in the pool, Barbara falls there, ends up on at the bottom of the pool, tries to escape, gets caught by the monster. The question still remains: why would the monster give her some time in the pool after it takes her to the Upside-Down? Barbara seemed to be unconscious there for a little while before trying to escape. An obvious explanation is that it's better for a show, but I wonder if there could  be an in-the-universe reason for this fact.

What I don't get completely is that Will gets a rifle (which we know is of little help) waiting for the monster, and then somehow ends up in the Upside-Down. If the monster brings him over there (physically), how does Will manage to escape?

Comment: Have you seen all of the episodes? I only ask because your very last question "how does Will manage to escape?" is actually shown. Though you could make the argument that he didn't actually escape as well.

Comment: I think he means , how Will manage to escape from the monster for so long time in Upside-Down.

Comment: @djmadscribbler: indeed I finished watching the show. I am not sure whether it's shown how Will managed to escape from the Monster in the very beginning (after the Monster took him to the Upside-Down).

Comment: @llya the show dont explain how this happen (well, i dont remember if it does) i think the monster have, for the very first time, a lot of food so maybe hes not hungry and are only stock the living food. He thinks it is impossible to scape from Upside-Down, so he leaves Will free. The other possibility is, he needs living humans for reproduction, Barb and Will have this slug things inside then, maybe he eats Barb after the incubation period

Answer (score 3):

The monster takes all his victims to the upside-down, and there he decides what he will do with them. The monster has the ability to enter the upside-down whenever he wants.

> in the last episode we see that Will has flashes that he is in the upside-down, he now probably also has that ability

It's possible that he opens a portal to bring people or things with him to the upside-down, like what he did with the deer. But he could also just bring people with him without a portal.

Once inside the upside-down, he can eat people right away, kill them to eat later or use them for some sort of (reproduction or energy pulling? like seen in the last episode, when Will is found with a tentacle or tube in his mouth).

We are never told how Will manage to escape from the monster for so long, and that is one of the [main unanswered questions](http://time.com/4426157/questions-stranger-things-still-needs-to-answer/) for season 2, but we can assume that:

- Some other thing attracted the monster the moment it was about to kill Will.
- Will managed to shoot the monster and escape.
- The monster wasn't hungry at the time (and let Will escape?)
- Will is one of the main characters and the plot is based on the possibility of saving him.

Barb wasn't so lucky (Not so important the history) and it all leads that she got killed right away.

Comment: I don't remember anything like what you say in your hidden text.

Comment: @sirjonsnow In the last episode, he has flashes of the upside-down, I will edit to make more clear...